# Kafka Streams unable to delete state directory during JUnit testing (using EmbeddedKafka)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I upgraded Kafka Streams to 3.0.1. With older versions, there is no problem as state directory is deleted after tests run. Upon upgrade to 3.0.1, it seems that Kafka Streams is unable to delete state directory. I tried calling FileUtils.deleteDirectory(...) during *@AfterAll*, but throws an IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: \data\user-state-store\app-group-id\global\rocksdb\app-state-store\LOCK
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2400) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2391) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2391) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2391) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2391) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try to call `KafkaStreams.cleanup()` ?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes, but it says "Failed to delete state store directory of C:\data\user-state-store\app-group-id for it is not empty"

Comment: Maybe you are hitting: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13787